# Cumulative link model with categorical or continuous predictors?

Tags: r, mixed-model, categorical-data, ordered-logit

I have data in a perception experiment where I show surfaces slanted at different angles and ask participants to judge whether the surface could be stood on. I also asked them how certain they are about their perceptual responses using a 7-point Likert scale. Here is a subset of the data:

```
SUB COND    TRIAL   REP ANGLE   CERTAINTY 

1   visual  1   1   24  6

1   visual  2   1   30  6

1   visual  3   1   48  7

1   visual  4   1   18  5

1   visual  5   1   36  6

1   visual  6   1   33  3

1   visual  7   1   27  6

1   visual  8   1   12  7

1   visual  9   1   42  7

1   visual  10  2   48  7

1   visual  11  2   33  4

1   visual  12  2   30  4

1   visual  13  2   42  7

1   visual  14  2   27  6

1   visual  15  2   24  6

1   visual  16  2   12  7

1   visual  17  2   36  7

1   visual  18  2   18  7

1   visual  19  3   30  4

1   visual  20  3   18  7

1   visual  21  3   33  6

1   visual  22  3   27  5

1   visual  23  3   36  7

1   visual  24  3   12  7

1   visual  25  3   48  7

1   visual  26  3   24  6

1   visual  27  3   42  7
```

I analyzed the data with a cumulative link model where certainty is an ordinal variable and angle is treated as a continuous predictor variable on an interval scale. Here is the model and output:

```
data$trialB<-data$TRIAL-(data$REP-1)*9  #trials nested within reps
data$idnum<-as.factor(data$SUB*1000+data$REP) #subject number defined for each rep
data$CERTAINTY <- factor(data$CERTAINTY)
fm <- clmm(CERTAINTY ~ ANGLE*COND +(trialB|idnum), data = data,Hess=TRUE)
summary(fm)


Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: CERTAINTY ~ ANGLE * COND + (trialB | idnum)
data:    data

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter      max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  1178 -1834.20 3692.39 1187(3229) 4.02e-02 1.7e+05

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr   
 idnum  (Intercept) 0.294610 0.54278         
        trialB      0.002469 0.04969  -1.000 
Number of groups:  idnum 132 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
ANGLE            -0.006263   0.007501  -0.835    0.404
CONDvisual       -0.096193   0.336045  -0.286    0.775
ANGLE:CONDvisual  0.002659   0.010555   0.252    0.801

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2 -4.25987    0.32605 -13.065
2|3 -3.20255    0.27404 -11.687
3|4 -2.30158    0.25454  -9.042
4|5 -1.49539    0.24625  -6.073
5|6 -0.66281    0.24224  -2.736
6|7  0.05606    0.24112   0.233
```

My problem is that there should be an effect of ANGLE such that certainty is minimal around 30 degrees. However, the output does not confirm that. If I change the ANGLE variable into a factor (i.e. a categorical variable), I will start getting the effects of ANGLE in the output:

```
data$ANGLE1 <- factor(data$ANGLE) 
fm2 <- clmm(CERTAINTY ~ ANGLE1*COND +(trialB|idnum), data = data,Hess=TRUE)
summary(fm2)

Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: CERTAINTY ~ ANGLE1 * COND + (trialB | idnum)
data:    data

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter       max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  1178 -1559.89 3171.79 3712(11231) 4.39e-03 3.5e+04

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr   
 idnum  (Intercept) 0.7032298 0.83859         
        trialB      0.0009656 0.03107  -1.000 
Number of groups:  idnum 132 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
ANGLE118             -1.9991     0.5861  -3.411 0.000647 ***
ANGLE124             -4.2766     0.5716  -7.482 7.32e-14 ***
ANGLE127             -4.8567     0.5754  -8.440  < 2e-16 ***
ANGLE130             -4.9210     0.5721  -8.602  < 2e-16 ***
ANGLE133             -4.7692     0.5740  -8.309  < 2e-16 ***
ANGLE136             -3.9440     0.5726  -6.888 5.67e-12 ***
ANGLE142             -2.6715     0.5784  -4.619 3.86e-06 ***
ANGLE148             -0.0415     0.7384  -0.056 0.955181    
CONDvisual           -1.1651     0.6372  -1.829 0.067467 .  
ANGLE118:CONDvisual   0.6994     0.7257   0.964 0.335178    
ANGLE124:CONDvisual   1.5613     0.6988   2.234 0.025463 *  
ANGLE127:CONDvisual   1.5620     0.6970   2.241 0.025027 *  
ANGLE130:CONDvisual   1.0764     0.6945   1.550 0.121154    
ANGLE133:CONDvisual   1.1225     0.6978   1.609 0.107689    
ANGLE136:CONDvisual   1.2579     0.7033   1.789 0.073695 .  
ANGLE142:CONDvisual   1.2967     0.7209   1.799 0.072050 .  
ANGLE148:CONDvisual   0.1090     0.8946   0.122 0.902997    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -8.2985     0.5918 -14.024
2|3  -7.1916     0.5627 -12.782
3|4  -6.1824     0.5507 -11.227
4|5  -5.1992     0.5437  -9.563
5|6  -4.0564     0.5375  -7.546
6|7  -2.9241     0.5315  -5.502
```

Which model is the correct one, statistically speaking?

Thanks!
Alen

Comment: What is `trialB` and why is it a random effect and not a fixed effect ?

Comment: There is no such a thing as "continues interval" variables! It is either "fully" continuous or discrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither model is "correct", statistically:

> *"Remember that all models are wrong; the practical question is how wrong do they have to be to not be useful."*
>
> Box, G. E. P.; Draper, N. R. (1987), Empirical Model-Building and Response Surfaces, John Wiley & Sons.

The first problem I see with both models is that the correlation between the random effects is estimated as $-1$. This is an indication of numerical and/or identification problems.  You have specified `trialB` as a random coeffcient  which estimates a random slope for the variable, however you haven't specified it as a fixed effect. Normally a variable that is a random coefficient would also be a fixed effect and the random effect. The fixed effect would be the "global" effect for the variable (ie an overall slope) and the random slopes would give each subject their own slope as a deviation from the overall slope. By excluding it as a fixed effect you are essentially saying that the overall slope is zero (because random effects have a mean of zero). If you really want random slopes for `trialB` I would suggest adding it as a fixed effect as well and see if a more reasonable correlation is estimated. If not, then it would be better to remove it as a random effect.

The second problem I see is that, in your OP, you say

> there should be an effect of ANGLE such that certainty is minimal around 30 degrees

So I interpret that is meaning you expect a non-linear association between the response variable and `ANGLE`. However in your first model you not fitting any nonlinear terms for `ANGLE`. So I would suggest adding a quadratic term. It would be a good idea to centre `ANGLE` first to avoid collinearity between the linear and quadratic terms.

The second model estimates a fixed effect for each level of `ANGLE`. This is another way to model non-linear change, though it is little harder to interpret if there are many levels. The fact that you see estimates that are not changing linearly  and in particular, that they are all negative with a minimum value for `ANGLE130` indicates that you *do* have nonlinearity and in particular that the minimum is at `ANGLE=30`, as you hypothesized.

So I would say that, while neither model is "correct", the second one is better than the first, though I would rather keep `ANGLE` numeric and introduce a quadratic term into the model, since it is easier to interpret and more parsimonious.

Comment: Robert - thanks a lot! I reran the model by keeping angle numeric, and included a quadratic, and voila - Angle^2 becomes significant! This actually makes a lot of sense psychologically: confidence judgments (certainty) are nonlinearly related to perceived angles.

Comment: @alen-hajnal glad to help ! Did you also resolve the implausible random effects correlation ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am using a repeated measures design where I have 9 different angles repeated 3 times each in random order. The repetitions are blocked to decrease the likelihood of having the same angle presented back to back. I was trying to build nested random effects such that trials are nested within repetitions and then further within subjects. I welcome any suggestions as to how to best specify random effects. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After I centered `ANGLE` and added `ANGLE^2`, I used the following model:

```
data$ANGLE <- (data$ANGLE)-30 #centered variable
data$ANGLE1 <- (data$ANGLE)^2

fm2 <- clmm(CERTAINTY ~ ANGLE*COND +ANGLE1*COND +(1+ANGLE|SUB), data = data,Hess=TRUE)
```

The output now shows a much lower correlation of random effects (0.040):

```
    Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: CERTAINTY ~ ANGLE * COND + ANGLE1 * COND + (1 + ANGLE | SUB)
data:    data

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter      max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  1178 -1460.26 2948.52 1542(9319) 1.68e-01 7.3e+05

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr  
 SUB    (Intercept) 0.85102  0.9225         
        ANGLE       0.02647  0.1627   0.040 
Number of groups:  SUB 44 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
ANGLE             -0.021042   0.036965  -0.569 0.569197    
CONDvisual         0.259612   0.316720   0.820 0.412394    
ANGLE1             0.023086   0.001605  14.385  < 2e-16 ***
ANGLE:CONDvisual   0.013147   0.051909   0.253 0.800063    
CONDvisual:ANGLE1 -0.006120   0.001837  -3.332 0.000862 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -3.7424     0.3212 -11.651
2|3  -2.5498     0.2595  -9.825
3|4  -1.4684     0.2368  -6.202
4|5  -0.3946     0.2289  -1.724
5|6   0.9193     0.2307   3.985
6|7   2.3037     0.2425   9.499
```

Is my model now specified correctly?

Comment: (+1)  Looks good to me.